# Meteor 1.3 and configuration

Tags: node.js, meteor

i have a simple question.
When you use node + webpack you can easily configure whatever you want.

For example i can write in config default path for my app modules.

Haw can i do it in Meteor 1.3? do they have some config file such Webpack?

Comment: You looking for [settings.json](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/)?

Comment: Thanks, it lock like what i was trying to find)

Comment: I'll move my comment to be an answer if that was correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor applications can store configuration options like API keys or global settings. An easy way to provide this configuration is with a `settings.json` file in the root of your Meteor application. The key/value pairs are available only on the server, but you can provide public access to settings by using `public`:

**settings.json**

```
{
  "privateKey": "privateValue",
  "public": {
    "publicKey": "publicValue"
  }
}
```

These values are available in your app using `Meteor.settings`.

**From the Full Meteor Docs:**

> Meteor.settings contains deployment-specific configuration options. You can initialize settings by passing the --settings option (which takes the name of a file containing JSON data) to meteor run or meteor deploy. When running your server directly (e.g. from a bundle), you instead specify settings by putting the JSON directly into the METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable. If the settings object contains a key named public, then Meteor.settings.public will be available on the client as well as the server. All other properties of Meteor.settings are only defined on the server. You can rely on Meteor.settings and Meteor.settings.public being defined objects (not undefined) on both client and server even if there are no settings specified. Changes to Meteor.settings.public at runtime will be picked up by new client connections.

A good write-up can also be found on [TheMeteorChef's Blog](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/)